# Stream data from browser to the mobile phone

Tags: mobile, google-chrome-extension, push-notification, stream

I'm developing app that will be in Chrome (as a plugin) and Google store. When user turn on the plugin it sends JSON data every few seconds to the mobile phone based on Android OS.

In some of my projects I've used websocket to stream the data from telephone central via proxy/service to the browser. I'd like to do something like that.

I'm wondering how to implement and what of existing services to use as a layer between browser and mobile app? I don't need a broadcasting because every user/plugin has own data.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement Google Cloud Messaging, especially if your data payload fits into 4kB per message; you will need a server that will re-route messages from the extension endpoint to the phone endpoint though.

- Extension registers with your server ID through GCM.
- Phone registers with your server through GCM.
- Extension sends a message upstream; your server receives it.
- Your server pushes the message to the phone downstream.

Chrome [natively supports GCM in extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/gcm) (but not FCM!), as does Android.

Comment: Is onesignal.com good alternative? I think it uses the same approach.